# Problem in interpreting probability as a set.

Tags: probability

If I have 3 independents events A, B and C. On the one hand,

($A$ and $B$) and ($A$ and $C$) = $A$ and $B$ and $C$.

So, $(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) = A \cap B \cap C$.

On the other hand.

$$P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$$
which is different of

$$P((A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C)) = P(A)P(C)P(B)^2.$$

Where's the error?

Appreciate.

Comment: You can only multiply individual probabilities *IF THE EVENTS ARE INDEPENDENT*.  Clearly $A \cap B$ and $B \cap C$ are not independent.

Comment: $(A\cap B)$ is not independent of $(B\cap C)$.  You can write the probability of an intersection of events as the product of the probabilities of the events if *and only if* those are independent.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you.

Comment: In fact, what you have shown is proof that $(A\cap B)$ and $(B\cap C)$ are not independent

Answer (score 1):

In your last line, you have implicitly used
$$  P((A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C)) = P(A \cap B)P(B \cap C)  \text{,}  $$
which is only true if the events $A \cap B$ and $B \cap C$ are independent.  Do you have $A \cap B$ and $B \cap C$ independent?